# can't understand why i didn't got exception using jsp, but got it with velocity?

Tags: spring, view, velocity

I have a spring mvc project.For views firstly i used jsp and it worked fine, but then i wanted to use velocity and got exception.Both views are similar except of syntax.I can't understand why it happens. That's my jsp:

```
<form:form action="updateDepartament" modelAttribute="editDepartament" method="POST">            
         <table>            
            <tr>
                <td>Id:</td>
                <td><form:input path="departamentId" readonly="true"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><spring:message code="label.title"/></td>
                <td><form:input path="title"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="title"/></td>
            </tr>
         </table>

         <input type="submit" value="submit">               
 <c:if test="${! empty editDepartament.depart_Employeers}">                        
                    <table>                            
                        <th>Id</th>                            
                        <th><spring:message code="label.firstName"/></th>
                        <th><spring:message code="label.lastName"/></th>
                        <th><spring:message code="label.salary"/></th>
                        <th><spring:message code="label.birthdate"/></th>
                        <th><spring:message code="label.active"/></th>                          
                        <tr>
                            <c:forEach var="empl" items="${editDepartament.depart_Employeers}" varStatus="status">
                                <tr>
                                <td><form:input path="depart_Employeers[${status.index}].id" readonly="true"/></td>
                                <td><form:input path="depart_Employeers[${status.index}].firstName" readonly="true"/></td>
                                <td><form:input path="depart_Employeers[${status.index}].lastName" readonly="true"/></td>
                                <td><form:input path="depart_Employeers[${status.index}].salary" readonly="true"/></td>
                                <td><form:input path="depart_Employeers[${status.index}].birthday" readonly="true"/></td>
                                <td><form:input path="depart_Employeers[${status.index}].active" readonly="true"/></td>
                                <td><a href="deleteEmployee/${empl.id}"><spring:message code="label.delete"/></a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </c:if>
        </form:form>
```

And this's my velocity template:

```
<form action="updateDepartament"  method="POST">
        #springBind("editDepartament")
         <table>            
            <tr>
                <td>Id:</td>
                <td>#springFormInput("editDepartament.departamentId" 'readonly="true"')</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><spring:message code="label.title"/></td>
                <td>#springFormInput("editDepartament.title" "")</td>
                <td>#springShowErrors("" "")</td>
            </tr>
         </table>            
         <input type="submit" value="submit">                    
                #if(!$editDepartament.depart_Employeers.isEmpty())
                     <table>
                        <th>Id</th>                            
                        <th>#springMessage("label.firstName")</th>
                        <th>#springMessage("label.lastName")</th>
                        <th>#springMessage("label.salary")</th>
                        <th>#springMessage("label.birthdate")</th>
                        <th>#springMessage("label.active")</th>                          
                        <tr>
                            #foreach($empl in $editDepartament.depart_Employeers)
                                <tr>
                                <td>#springFormInput("editDepartament.depart_Employeers[$velocityCount].id"             'readonly="true"')</td>
                                <td>#springFormInput("editDepartament.depart_Employeers[$velocityCount].firstName"      'readonly="true"') </td>
                                <td>#springFormInput("editDepartament.depart_Employeers[$velocityCount].lastName"       'readonly="true"')</td>
                                <td>#springFormInput("editDepartament.depart_Employeers[$velocityCount].salary"         'readonly="true"')</td>
                                <td>#springFormInput("editDepartament.depart_Employeers[$velocityCount].birthday"       'readonly="true"')</td>
                                <td>#springFormInput("editDepartament.depart_Employeers[$velocityCount].active"         'readonly="true"')</td>
                                <td><a href="deleteEmployee/${empl.id}">#springMessage("label.delete")</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            #end
                        </tr>
                    </table>
               #end
        </form>
```

Exception occurs after changing the title:

```
HTTP Status 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.mycompany.employeers.domain.Employee; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.mycompany.employeers.domain.Employee
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)


root cause 

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.mycompany.employeers.domain.Employee; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.mycompany.employeers.domain.Employee
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:654)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:793)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:664)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy723.editDepartament(Unknown Source)
    com.mycompany.employeers.web.EmployeesController.updateDepartament(EmployeesController.java:204)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)


root cause 

org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.mycompany.employeers.domain.Employee
    org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:219)
    org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:397)
    org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:78)
    org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.writeElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:755)
    org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1143)
    org.hibernate.action.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:39)
    org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
    org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
    org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:171)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy723.editDepartament(Unknown Source)
    com.mycompany.employeers.web.EmployeesController.updateDepartament(EmployeesController.java:204)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

And responsible for this view part of controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateDepartament", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateDepartament(@ModelAttribute("editDepartament")Departament dep, BindingResult result){
        departamentValidator.validate(dep, result);
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "editDepartament";
        }
        service.editDepartament(dep);
        return "redirect:/listDepartaments";
    }
```

Maybe someone knows how to solve this and can explain me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a closer look at the exception, then you will see that the exception does not occure while rendering but wile invoking the  `service.editDepartament(dep);` from your `EmployeesController.updateDepartament` method.

```
....
com.mycompany.employeers.web.EmployeesController.updateDepartament(EmployeesController.java:204)
....
```

For me it looks like that one of the entities that are referenced by `Departament dep` are detached from your Hibernate Entity Manager. -- *But I can not give you more details form the limited amount of code you posted.*

So lets summarize: the problem is somewhere in the requesthandling (related to hibernate), but I strongly doubt that it is related to the view (Except there is some filter (like open entity manager in view) that is only triggerd for the requests that render jsps but not velocity templates).

Comment: Thanks a lot Ralph for answer!

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution.I didn't add to my entity Departament cascadeType.All:

```
@OneToMany(fetch= FetchType.EAGER,cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="DEPARTAMENTID")    
    private List<Employee> depart_Employeers;
```

Now it works, but I confused a bit ..Why does application work with jsp and without defining cascadeType?